# hook_block_view() $delta alias value

Tags: blocks

```
function loading_icon_block_view($delta='') {
    switch($delta) {

        case 'loading_icon':
            $block = array(
                //Title of Block
                'subject' => t('Loading Icon Example Code'),

                //Content contained
                'content' => loading_icon_gen_content(),
            );
            break;

        /* Always returns ? */
        default:
            //Tested used to find out $delta if content not showing
            $block['content'] = 'Delta: '.$delta;
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

This works fine in conjunction with `hook_form()` and using `drupal_set_message` on the block generated I see that I get both loading_icon and loading-icon as the $delta (if I duplicate the current case to loading-icon then I get the same content printed twice).

I haven't set loading-icon anywhere. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: You need to implement `hook_block_info()` too. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did. The module is displayed correctly as a block using block_info() and I also set up the .info with dependencies. I'm new to the render array concepts and don't know how the name `loading-icon` is being generated as my hooks and .info,.module are labelled loading_icon.